# Apache Storm JMS Spout reconnect

Tags: hadoop, jms, apache-storm, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I am using Storm JMS Spout to connect to TibcoEMS and it works great.

We are having problem with making the Storm Spout to automatically reconnect when there is a failover in TIBCO EMS Server.

Is this possible in Storm to automatically reconnect to jmsURL?

We are not enabling the heartbeats and Tibco EMS is using Veritas failover and not the EMS failover.

How can we configure that in SpringJMS Application Context for Spout ????

Comment: i am trying to create spout to connect to TIBCOEMS Topic. not able to connect to topic.can u tell me how u wrote JMSspout?

Comment: SpringJmsProvider jmsTopicQueueProvider = new SpringJmsProvider(TopicAppContextResource, "connectionFactory",
            "destination");

Comment: TridentJmsSpout TridentTopicSpout = new TridentJmsSpout();
        TridentTopicSpout.withJmsProvider(jmsTopicQueueProvider);
        // TridentSpout.withJmsAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        TridentTopicSpout.withTupleProducer(new TradeJMSTuplePropducer());

Comment: <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate"> 
        <property name="environment"> 
            <props> 
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://fgbnlkd.kjdbfvljbg.local:8334</prop>               
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.apache.activemq.jndi</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>               
            </props> 
        </property> 
    </bean>

Comment: <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>BebDataQueueConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
         <ref local="jndiTemplate"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: <bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>DMY.NetAsset</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
         <ref local="jndiTemplate"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: thank you rajesh. I am not using spring here.Below is the code i am trying

this.connectionFactory  = new TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory(server_url);
    
     Connection _connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("", "");
 
     Session session = _connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     Queue receiverQueue = session.createQueue(queue_name);
     this.destination = (Destination) receiverQueue    ;